# Технический вопрос по устройству передачи файлов с фронта на бэк

Tags: php, javascript, formdata

Вопрос на который мне не дали ответ поисковики, я старался честно.

Есть опыт работы с передачей файлов и никогда не было проблем с их передачей, вопрос к знатокам и любителям досконально изучить проблему.

Я передаю `FormData` с файлом на сервер, на сервере php есть доступ к `$_FILES` где мы можем узнать его имя в папке `tmp` на сервере и манипулировать им.

**Вопрос:** Каким образом файл появляется на сервере, что `js` говорит для того чтобы этот файл был сохранён, в каком формате он передаёт на сервер и кто, получая команду от `js`, сохраняет его в папку `tmp`, а так же формирует информацию о нём в `php` переменной `$_FILES`?

Comment: Добрый день. А какое отношение вопрос имеет к yii2, gridview?

Comment: Да и js тут тоже непонятно каким боком в вопрос попал. Js только говорит - на файлик. Аналогично сабмиту в html форме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что JS говорит для того чтобы этот файл был сохранён

Ничего. Он отправляет файл, а что делать с ним, сервер уже сам решает.

> в каком формате он передаёт на сервер

Скорее всего, в [формате `multipart/form-data`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388). Во всяком случае, это стандартный способ загрузки файлов, которым пользуются обычные HTML-ные формы. Теоретически содержимое файлов можно загружать и другими способами, но это сложнее.

> кто, получая команду от JS, сохраняет его в папку `tmp`, а так же формирует информацию о нём в php переменной `$_FILES`?

Этим занимается сам PHP ещё до того, как запустит ваш код.

Comment: Спасибо, но все же хотелось узнать подробнее что же делает php и как он отлавливает файл, можно ли это как-то влиять на это

Comment: @NikitaShahov отлавливает где? Он получает HTTP-запрос с содержимым файла и записывает этот файл сам, а имя запоминает в указанную суперглобаль.

Comment: Спасибо, так понятнее, но все же не понимаю на низком уровне как выполняются манипуляции с файлом до его записи и можно ли на это влиять

Comment: @NikitaShahov какие манипуляции? На насколько низком уровне?